# Moving a range of cells to another sheet based on value in cell

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I don't even know how to word this correctly which is doubtlessly why i am having trouble.

So I have 3 columns, `names`, `time`, `values` in each row. 
I want to take all the times next to the same name and put them in another sheet, under a column headed by the persons name.

I would be happy with the first part but in addition, if possible, I would also like to make sure that the when the times get posted they are related to the values they were originally next to.

example:

```
john     7    10  
john     5    20  
john   6.5    30                                        
amy     14    10             
amy      8    20    
amy      2    40
```

becomes

```
      john    amy  
10       7     14  
20       5      8  
30     6.5   
40              2
```

Comment: Learn about the OFFSET, MATCH and INDEX formulas and use them.

Comment: ok, just read up on all 3. INDEX seems kind of relevant but i'm still not sure how i would use that to accomplish what i am after.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
j = 6
Cells(1, 6).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value
For i = 2 To 6
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(1, j).Value Then
        Cells(1, j + 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

Range("C1:C6").Copy
Range("E2:E7").PasteSpecial

Range("E2:E7").Sort Key1:=Range("E2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
Range("E2:E7").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

For k = 1 To 6
    For m = 6 To 9
        For n = 2 To 6
            If Cells(k, 1).Value = Cells(1, m).Value And Cells(k, 3).Value = Cells(n, 5).Value Then
                Cells(n, m).Value = Cells(k, 2).Value
            End If
        Next n
    Next m
Next k
```

This code solves your particular example. Keep in mind that this is not a versatile code so you gonna have to change the limits of the loops and ranges in your actual thing.

Answer (score -1):

No need for VBA here, just use the powerful tools Excel has already built in to analyze your data:
[Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and the result will be like below. If you change values in the orginal data you will just need to update the PivotTable.

[image]
<sup>*Image 1: Original data and PivotTable side by side (sorry for the German screenshot).*</sup>

Comment: Why the heck did that get down-voted? This is a perfect use case for a PivotTable.

Comment: Every time i try a pivot table i get errors about invalid references

Comment: If that comment meant to be a question you muste be more precise. Because PivotTables work like a charm (as you can see in my post) you are probably doing something wrong. Therefore we need to know exactly what you did and the exact error massage you got. Best is to ask a new question showing with screenshots what you did and explaining what happened.